# How to make listview which are notifying new data is arrived in android

Tags: android, facebook, listview

I am making an app for bollywood news
When i am opening app it loads data from rss feed and inflates into listview using custom array adapter
[image]

I want to make that New Posts section when app opens next time..
This is exactly same as facebook mobile app.
Please Help me.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: When you get new data from your background serverice add those data to ListView data holder and notify ListView adapter.

Answer (score 3):

you can do by adding service which is run in background continuously and waiting for new data. when new data found you can show up your new posts section.

Comment: can you please explain me in brief... @prshntjjl

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @prshntjjl create service for continuously checking new data.

You can use **alarmManager.setRepeating** kind of stuff to run something in repeating manner which calls your remote service and if new data available , you can use **localBroadcast** to listening activity with new data.

Comment: please can you give me some example related with this..because i dont have any idea about service